# How to Connect Azure Data Factory to a Peer Network on a different VNET

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create Peer Virtual Network between my Azure Data Factory on one VNET with resources on another VNET, (specifically SQLDBs). I'm trying to follow the guide

Here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-peering

But I'm not having much luck.

Can someone let me know if its actually possible?

Comment: Could you explain what are the issues you've encountered ? Why is is not working ?

Comment: Whenever I try to connect to SQLDB from ADF I'm constantly getting the message that the firewall is blocking ADF's and that I need to allow its ip address through the firewall.

Comment: So databrick has it s own vnet, you wanna use a custom IR with managed vnet (ADF) and peer it to the databrick vnet ? or use ADF private endpoint to connect ot the databrick vnet ?

Comment: I was just wondering why you mentioned databrick, but then I saw the link above. However, I'm not trying to connect to databricks. I'm trying to connect to SQLDB from ADF

Comment: so you have a vnet. your sql db have vnet integration or you re using private endpoint to connect the sql db to the vnet ?

Comment: I mean is it azure sql or sql on vm ?

Comment: Its azure sql db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232611/discussion-between-thomas-and-patterson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can integrate both the ADF and the Azure SQL with the VNet using the private endpoint, peer the two VNet, then you can access the Azure SQL from the ADF from the VNet. And you also need to add the private IP address of the ADF in the whitelist of the Azure SQL to allow the ADF to access.